# Feed XML content into a wordpress page

Tags: xml, wordpress

I am looking for a widget or similar for feeding some xml content (articles) into a wordpress page.

Comment: Is this something you intend to program against? I mean, is it a programming problem?

Answer (score 2):

"xml content" is very generic, perhaps you could elaborate on what you're wanting to do with this XML?